# MySQL SELECT query works but an UPDATE query with same WHERE clause does not

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

When rows are excluded in an UPDATE query, why does the database engine try to set an incorrect datetime first and stops execution?

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` DATETIME NULL
)

INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `order_date`) VALUES
("test nodate", NULL),
("test 2021-10-27", NULL);

-- Both rows are selected with a formatted date taken from the `name`
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(`name`, 10), "%Y-%m-%d") AS `date part from name` FROM `test`;

-- The first row with an invalid date in the name is correctly excluded
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(`name`, 10), "%Y-%m-%d") AS `date part from name` FROM `test`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(`name`, 10), "%Y-%m-%d") IS NOT NULL;

-- Error: invalid datetime "est nodate", but that row should be excluded
UPDATE `test` SET
`order_date` = DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(`name`, 10), "%Y-%m-%d")
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(`name`, 10), "%Y-%m-%d") IS NOT NULL;
```

DB Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iUmjxZz3u5bpZesfiD4pzY/1

When trying for example this update query to set an invalid datetime, the engine doesnt throw the same error, while I expect it to be the same of the errornous update  statement above:

```
UPDATE `test`
SET `order_date` = "invalid"
WHERE `name` <> `name`;
```

This update is succesful and no rows are updated, but I tried to force the invalid datetime error.

Are functions like DATE_FORMAT() special case in order of execution or something?
Is a workaround possible to make the UPDATE query succesfully execute?

Comment: Does the table has an id autoincrement ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha The real table in my database does, the table in the fiddle does not.

Answer (score 1):

Error is detected in WHERE, not in SET.

```sql
UPDATE `test`
SET `order_date` = NOW()
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(`name`, 10), "%Y-%m-%d") IS NOT NULL;
```

produces the same error.

And the error occurence is defined by SQL Server mode.

See [Strict SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0bcb8862b10fb8af16b8e2ffb1ae46c

Comment: Nice reproducal of the error! Why is the SELECT with the same DATE_FORMAT condition not giving an error? And how to get a working UPDATE query that updates the rows from the working SELECT?

Comment: @Piemol Investigate the whole fiddle, not a part of it. You must disable strict mode for to execute your UPDATE. *Why is the SELECT with the same DATE_FORMAT condition not giving an error?* Because SELECT does not change the data. *Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE.*

Answer (score 1):

The operation:

```
DATE_FORMAT('foo bar baz', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

results in the following **warning**:

```
1292-Incorrect datetime value: '...'
```

Now, depending on [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html), the **warning will be treated as error in data-change statements**. This explains why your `SELECT` statement works (with warnings) but `INSERT` does not (the warnings are treated as errors).

[Full demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=940703ae7aa8bfe7bfc973c5e86ee0f7)

Comment: I now read that part of the mysql documentation. The SELECT never throws a warning? The UPDATE won't throw an error nor warning when changing it in an `UPDATE IGNORE` statement while preserving the `SQL_MODE` `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. I'm helped now, but don't understand the full 100% of this behavior :) **EDIT:** The fiddle is not throwing these errors, but in my local database it is (Y)

Comment: In summary, date functions will always throw warnings, if any. You can see them by executing `SHOW WARNINGS` after executing a query. In strict mode the warnings are treated as errors. But yeah, `UPDATE IGNORE` is better instead of changing SQL modes.